# Performing a calculation on every value in a variable of a netCDF file

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I am currently working with around 40 NetCDF files. I have been trying to perform a calculation on every value in a particular variable of each file, however when I go to plot the new calculated variable, none of the values have changed. I have opend the file with xarray and then selected the variable. How do I get the new calculated values to stick. I have tried multiple return statements aswell. Here is what I have so far:

def calculation_1(file):

```
    # Open Global attributes
    with xr.open_dataset(file) as s5p_variables:
        print(colored('Global attributes of product:\n', 'blue'), s5p_variables)

    raw_no2 = s5p_variables['tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density'][0]
    for x in range(raw_no2.shape[0]):
        for y in range(raw_no2.shape[1]):
            y_intercept = (2*(raw_no2[x][y]))/100  
            slope = -y_intercept/100  
            raw_no2[x][y] = slope*10 + y_intercept
```

pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell from your code snippet what you're doing wrong there. You can read about [how to create a minimal, reproducible example here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I've tried to reproduce your problem with an example below which demonstrates that the values should change. You can also avoid looping over each value as `xarray` can `broadcast` your calculations on each grid-point, which is much faster than using for loops.

```
data = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(2, 3), dims=("x", "y"), coords={"x": [10, 20]})
>>data
<xarray.DataArray (x: 2, y: 3)>
array([[ 0.27623202, -1.08740069, -0.67368971],
      [ 0.11364841, -1.47842655,  0.52498767]])
Coordinates:
* x        (x) int64 10 20
Dimensions without coordinates: y

y_intercept = (2*(raw_no2[x][y]))/100  
slope = -y_intercept/100  
raw_no2[x][y] = slope*10 + y_intercept
y_intercept = 2*data/100
slope = - y_intercept/100
data= slope*10 + y_intercept

>>data
<xarray.DataArray (x: 2y: 3)>
array([[-0.01121879,  0.02355238, -0.01290332],
       [ 0.01947954,  0.00112604, -0.02490705]])
Coordinates:
* x      (x) int64    10 20
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked perfectly. The problem seemed for be with the for loop. Once this was removed, the calculation performed fine